# duplicate value for pkey constraint

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, primary-key

I use PostgreSQL as a sql database to store my daily generated data, the problem is that the primary key constraint gets violated every time i try to add another lot of data on a different date

I have used "COPY "wsp" FROM 'C:\tmp\persons.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER; to export csv file.
I store warehouse data which contains 15-16 tables of different kinds of information each one has a unique primary key. i have to import the data on a daily basis where once i dump the data the next try of dumping the data gives a error of violating the unique constraint of the primary key

i have to dump the data on a daily basis until i have completed my work on stored procedures

for example: in the wsp table i have a set of warehouse's this is a unique set of a row of a particular date but as i try to load the data for the next day for the same set of the warehouse's the primary key is to violate

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "1.WSP_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key ("WAREHOUSEMAN_ID")=(9996059) already exists. CONTEXT: 
>   COPY 1.WSP, line 2 SQL state: 23505

Comment: Dumping data won't cause this error, but restoring the dump can. Please describe the procedure with some more technical details. How exactly are the numbers generated that make up the primary key? We have to understand what you are doing well enough to see where the problem comes from.

Comment: I am simple Importing the daily generated csv files

Comment: Sorry, New to this

Comment: command used is "COPY "wsp" 
FROM 'C:\tmp\persons.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Comment: i have already mentioned my problem in the top statement

Comment: No, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58263756/edit) and add it there. I'm not angry at you, just trying to guide you.